# DTD appearance moddifiers

Tags: xml, dtd

If an *ELEMENT* appearance is obligatory, **it must appear with content like this one:**

DTD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<!ELEMENT race (runner+)>
<!ELEMENT runner (#PCDATA)>
```

XML

```
<!DOCTYPE race SYSTEM "race.dtd">
<race>
    <runner>Runner1</runner>
    <runner>Runner2</runner>
</race>
```

**Or it can be an empty element?:**

XML

```
<!DOCTYPE race SYSTEM "race.dtd">
<race>
    <runner/>
</race>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be an empty element. Both of your samples are valid.